# Saving a selection in drop down list in php

Tags: php

How saving a selection of user in drop down list ? This code doesn't work.

In function 's file :

```
function selection($min,$max,$nom){
            echo "<select name=$nom>";
            for($i=$min;$i<=$max;$i++){
                if(isset($_REQUEST["'$nom'"])) {
                    $selected = 'selected';
                } else {
                    $selected='';
                }
                echo "<option value=$i selected=$selected>$i</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
    }
```

Part of page concerned :

```
        <td> Semaine </td>
        <td> <?php selection(1, 39, 'semaine'); ?> </td>
        <td>
            <input type="SUBMIT" name="afficher" value="Afficher"/>
        </td>
        </table>
        </form>
        <?php 
        if(isset($_REQUEST['afficher'])){
            $semaine = $_REQUEST['semaine'];                                
        ?>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change

```
for($i=$min;$i<=$max;$i++){
            if(isset($_REQUEST["'$nom'"])) {
                $selected = 'selected';
            } else {
                $selected='';
            }
            echo "<option value=$i selected=$selected>$i</option>";
        }
```

to

```
for($i=$min;$i<=$max;$i++){
            if(isset($_REQUEST[$nom]) && ($_REQUEST[$nom] == $i) ) {
                $selected = 'selected="selected"';
            } else {
                $selected='';
            }
            echo "<option value=$i $selected>$i</option>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try and **you will get selected number**

```
<?php function selection($min,$max,$nom){
        echo "<select name=$nom>";
        for($i=$min;$i<=$max;$i++){
            if(isset($_REQUEST[$nom]) && ($_REQUEST[$nom] == $i) ) {
                $selected = 'selected="selected"';
            } else {
                $selected='';
            }
            echo "<option value=$i $selected>$i</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";}
    ?>
```